# How delete method with calls in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

Consider a code example:

```
public Class TestClass {

    private void methodToDelete(int i, String s) {
        System.out.println(s + i);
    }

    public void anotherMethod(){
        System.out.println("Do some logic");
        methodToDelete(1, "1");
        methodToDelete(2, "2");
        System.out.println("Do some logic");
    }
}
```

When I used "Safe delete" in Intellij Idea, I get method to be deleted, but invocations still there:

```
public Class TestClass {

    //Method was deleted

    public void anotherMethod(){
        System.out.println("Do some logic");
        methodToDelete(1, "1"); //stil there
        methodToDelete(2, "2"); //stil there
        System.out.println("Do some logic");
    }
}
```

It is possible to delete both: method declaration and any method calls?

**UPDATED**
Also I can delete method body and use "Inline", but may there is more elegant solution? :)

Comment: I guess, it is done intentionally. Since when you remove a method you will definitely change your application logic, which in turn is quite harmful.

Comment: While that's true, I would sometimes like to remove a private method and all its calls. Then again, that's easily done with a find and replace on .*methodName.*?;

Comment: Here a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044888/1472483 you should clear the inside of method then ctrl + alt + N :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it wouldn't make much sense to automatically just delete all calls of a method, that could seriously break the source code. You can click 'View usages' of the method, iterate through them manually and replace/remove them as necessary, then you re-run the 'safe delete'..