# IntelliJ remove all uses of a method?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ gives useful functionality to see all usages of a method, and to check for usages before delete.

Is there a way to *delete* all usages of a method?

Comment: How would the IDE know how much to delete?

Answer (score 17):

Yes you can, but it is not safe. If you are *really* sure that you want to delete all usages, then you can:

- Empty the method body manually
- Inline the method and let it remove all invocations  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

You could seriously break the source code. Safe-deleting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is the better solution, that is, iterating through the invocations and deleting them manually.

Even if you empty & inline the method, make sure you first double-check the invocations.

---

**Example - Before inline:**

[image: Before inline]

---

**Result of inline:**

[image: After inline]

Comment: +1 for the second part of the answer. The first part doesn't actually answer the question, because it doesn't do the work 'safely'

Comment: True. I have updated my answer and added more warnings. Even a 10k user should be warned.